# Function showing incorrect results

Tags: r, function, plot, bar-chart, boxplot

I have a dataset with 5 columns. The 5 columns are

1. The household code ("Code"),
2. A binary variable ("usage") indicating whether the water is used for domestic or professional purposes (1. means domestic use and 2 means professional use).
3. The number of household members ("housemembers"),  only in the case of domestic use, otherwise the corrsponding value is NA.
4. A code that refers to the neighborhood the household belongs to and
   the consumption ("area").
5. The size of the house in square meters ("size").

The pricing method is the following:

The first 25 cubic meters are charged at 0.5 euro, the next 20 at 0.8 euro and from there on at 1 euro. For example, a household with a consumption of 48 cubic meters will pay 25 * 0.5 + 20 * 0.8 + 3* 1 = 31.5 euros, while another with a consumption of 30 cubic meters will pay 25*0.5 + 5*0.8 = 16.5 euros.

If the water is used for professional use then there is a one-time surcharge of 10 euros regardless of consumption. If there are more than 5 members in the household, there is a 10% discount on the final amount.

If the size is over 120 square meters then (and only then) there is an extra fee of 0.5 euros for every square meter over 120 square meters. For example, a property with a size of 140 square meters will pay for the 20 excess square meters another 10 euros extra.

Finally the final amount is taxed at VAT 13%.

I need to calculate the final amount each household will pay. The function needs to takes as input parameters the characteristics of the household and return the amount.

Here is my code, in R:

```
calculate_water_bill <- function(household_code, water_use, household_members, neighborhood_code, consumption, house_size) {
  # Initialize variables
  amount = 0
  
  # Calculate base amount based on consumption
  if (consumption <= 25) {
    amount = consumption * 0.5
  } else if (consumption <= 45) {
    amount = 25 * 0.5 + (consumption - 25) * 0.8
  } else {
    amount = 25 * 0.5 + 20 * 0.8 + (consumption - 45) * 1
  }
  
  # Apply surcharge for commercial use
  if (water_use == 2) {
    amount = amount + 10
  }
  
  # Apply discount for households with more than 5 members
  if (water_use == 1 && household_members > 5) {
    amount = amount * 0.9
  }
  
  # Apply extra fee for house size over 120 square meters
  if (house_size > 120) {
    extra_size = house_size - 120
    extra_fee = extra_size * 0.5
    amount = amount + extra_fee
  }
  
  # Calculate final amount including VAT
  final_amount = amount * 1.13
  
  return(final_amount)
}


# Assuming your dataset is stored in a data frame called 'dataset'

# Create an empty vector to store the calculated amounts
amounts <- vector()

# Iterate over each row in the dataset
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  # Get the characteristics of the household from each column
  household_code <- data[i, "Code"]
  water_use <- data[i, "usage"]
  household_members <- data[i, "housemembers"]
  neighborhood_code <- data[i, "area"]
  consumption <- data[i, "consum"]
  house_size <- data[i, "size"]
  
  # Calculate the amount for the household using the calculate_water_bill function
  amount_to_pay <- calculate_water_bill(household_code, water_use, household_members, neighborhood_code, consumption, house_size)
  
  # Append the calculated amount to the 'amounts' vector
  amounts <- c(amounts, amount_to_pay)
}

# Print the calculated amounts for all households
print(amounts)
```

The code seems correct at first glance, as  nrow(data)=length(amounts), where "data" is my dataset.

However, when I try to interpret the results, I understand that there is a mistake somewhere.

For example, `barplot(amounts, data$usage)` gives me the following plot, which shows that one of the "amount" values is negative:

[image]

```r
boxplot(data$housemembers, amounts)
```

also gives me the following result, despite the fact that some houses have up to 9 tenants:`

[image]

If anyone knows where I made the mistake, I'll appreaciate that very much.

Reproducible code:

```
data_struct <- structure(list(Code = c(10002L, 10003L, 10004L, 10005L, 10006L, 
10007L, 10008L, 10009L, 10010L, 10011L, 10012L, 10013L, 10014L, 
10015L, 10016L, 10017L, 10018L, 10019L, 10020L, 10021L, 10022L, 
10023L, 10024L, 10025L, 10026L, 10027L, 10028L, 10031L, 10032L, 
10033L, 10034L, 10035L, 10036L, 10037L, 10038L, 10039L, 10040L, 
10041L, 10042L, 10043L, 10044L, 10045L, 10046L, 10047L, 10048L, 
10049L, 10050L, 10051L, 10052L, 10053L, 10054L, 10055L, 10056L, 
10057L, 10058L, 10059L, 10060L, 10061L, 10062L, 10063L, 10064L, 
10065L, 10066L, 10067L, 10068L, 10069L, 10070L, 10071L, 10072L, 
10073L, 10074L, 10075L, 10076L, 10077L, 10078L, 10079L, 10080L, 
10081L, 10082L, 10083L, 10084L, 10085L, 10086L, 10087L, 10088L, 
10089L, 10090L, 10091L, 10092L, 10093L, 10094L, 10095L, 10096L, 
10097L, 10098L, 10099L, 10100L, 10101L, 10102L, 10103L, 10104L, 
10105L, 10106L, 10107L, 10108L, 10109L, 10110L, 10111L, 10112L, 
10113L, 10114L, 10115L, 10116L, 10117L, 10118L, 10119L, 10120L, 
10121L, 10122L, 10123L, 10124L, 10126L, 10127L, 10128L, 10129L, 
10130L, 10131L, 10132L, 10133L, 10134L, 10135L, 10136L, 10137L, 
10138L, 10139L, 10140L, 10141L, 10142L, 10143L, 10144L, 10145L, 
10146L, 10147L, 10148L, 10149L, 10150L, 10151L, 10152L, 10153L, 
10154L, 10155L, 10156L, 10157L, 10158L, 10159L, 10160L, 10161L, 
10162L, 10163L, 10164L, 10165L, 10166L, 10167L, 10168L, 10169L, 
10170L, 10171L, 10172L, 10173L, 10174L, 10175L, 10176L, 10177L, 
10178L, 10179L, 10180L, 10181L, 10182L, 10183L, 10184L, 10185L, 
10186L, 10187L, 10188L, 10189L, 10190L, 10191L, 10192L, 10193L, 
10194L, 10195L, 10196L, 10197L, 10198L, 10199L, 10200L, 10201L, 
10202L, 10203L, 10204L, 10205L, 10206L, 10207L, 10208L, 10209L, 
10210L, 10211L, 10212L, 10213L, 10214L, 10215L, 10216L, 10217L, 
10218L, 10219L, 10220L, 10221L, 10222L, 10223L, 10224L, 10225L, 
10226L, 10227L, 10228L, 10229L, 10230L, 10231L, 10232L, 10233L, 
10234L, 10235L, 10236L, 10237L, 10238L, 10239L, 10240L, 10241L, 
10242L, 10243L, 10244L, 10245L, 10246L, 10247L, 10248L, 10249L, 
10250L, 10251L, 10252L, 10253L, 10254L, 10255L, 10256L, 10257L, 
10258L, 10259L, 10260L, 10261L, 10262L, 10263L, 10264L, 10265L, 
10266L, 10267L, 10268L, 10269L, 10270L, 10271L, 10272L, 10273L, 
10274L, 10275L, 10276L, 10277L, 10278L, 10279L, 10280L, 10281L, 
10282L, 10283L, 10284L, 10285L, 10286L, 10287L, 10288L, 10289L, 
10290L, 10291L, 10292L, 10293L, 10294L, 10295L, 10296L, 10297L, 
10298L, 10299L, 10300L, 10301L, 10302L, 10303L, 10304L, 10305L, 
10306L, 10307L, 10308L, 10309L, 10310L, 10311L, 10312L, 10313L, 
10314L, 10315L, 10316L, 10317L, 10318L, 10319L, 10320L, 10321L, 
10322L, 10323L, 10324L, 10325L, 10326L, 10327L, 10328L, 10329L, 
10330L, 10331L, 10332L, 10333L, 10334L, 10335L, 10336L, 10337L, 
10338L, 10339L, 10340L, 10341L, 10342L, 10343L, 10344L, 10345L, 
10346L, 10347L, 10348L, 10349L, 10350L, 10351L, 10352L, 10353L, 
10354L, 10355L, 10356L, 10357L, 10358L, 10359L, 10360L, 10361L, 
10362L, 10363L, 10364L, 10365L, 10366L, 10367L, 10368L, 10369L, 
10370L, 10371L, 10372L, 10373L, 10374L, 10375L, 10376L, 10377L, 
10378L, 10379L, 10380L, 10381L, 10382L, 10383L, 10384L, 10385L, 
10386L, 10387L, 10388L, 10389L, 10390L, 10391L, 10392L, 10393L, 
10394L, 10395L, 10396L, 10397L, 10398L, 10399L, 10400L, 10401L, 
10402L, 10403L, 10404L, 10405L, 10406L, 10407L, 10408L, 10409L, 
10410L, 10411L, 10412L, 10413L, 10414L, 10415L, 10416L, 10417L, 
10418L, 10419L, 10420L, 10421L, 10422L, 10423L, 10424L, 10425L, 
10426L, 10427L, 10428L, 10429L, 10430L, 10431L, 10432L, 10433L, 
10434L, 10435L, 10436L, 10437L, 10438L, 10439L, 10440L, 10441L, 
10442L, 10443L, 10444L, 10445L, 10446L, 10447L, 10448L, 10449L, 
10450L, 10451L, 10452L, 10453L, 10454L, 10455L, 10456L, 10457L, 
10458L, 10459L, 10460L, 10461L, 10462L, 10463L, 10464L, 10465L, 
10466L, 10467L, 10468L, 10469L, 10470L, 10471L, 10472L, 10473L, 
10474L, 10475L, 10476L, 10477L, 10478L, 10479L, 10480L, 10481L, 
10482L, 10483L, 10484L, 10485L, 10486L, 10487L, 10488L, 10489L, 
10490L, 10491L, 10492L, 10493L, 10494L, 10495L, 10496L, 10497L, 
10498L, 10499L, 10500L, 10501L, 10502L, 10503L, 10504L, 10505L, 
10506L, 10507L, 10508L, 10509L, 10510L, 10511L, 10512L, 10513L, 
10514L, 10515L, 10516L, 10517L, 10518L, 10519L, 10520L, 10521L, 
10522L, 10523L, 10524L, 10525L, 10526L, 10527L, 10528L, 10529L, 
10530L, 10531L, 10532L, 10533L, 10534L, 10535L, 10536L, 10537L, 
10538L, 10539L, 10540L, 10541L, 10542L, 10543L, 10544L, 10545L, 
10546L, 10547L, 10548L, 10549L, 10550L, 10551L, 10552L, 10553L, 
10554L, 10555L, 10556L, 10557L, 10558L, 10559L, 10560L, 10561L, 
10562L, 10563L, 10564L, 10565L, 10566L, 10567L, 10568L, 10569L, 
10570L, 10571L, 10572L, 10573L, 10574L, 10575L, 10576L, 10577L, 
10578L, 10579L, 10580L, 10581L, 10582L, 10583L, 10584L, 10585L, 
10586L, 10587L, 10588L, 10589L, 10590L, 10591L, 10592L, 10593L, 
10594L, 10595L, 10596L, 10597L, 10598L, 10599L, 10600L, 10601L, 
10602L, 10603L, 10604L), usage = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), housemembers = c(2L, 6L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, NA, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 4L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 7L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, NA, 4L, NA, 4L, 4L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, NA, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
7L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
3L, NA, 2L, 5L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 5L, 2L, NA, 
2L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, NA, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, NA, 4L, 7L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, NA, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, NA, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, NA, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, NA, 3L, 
4L, NA, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, NA, 4L, 2L, 
NA, 5L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, NA, 1L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, 1L, 
2L, NA, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L), area = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), consum = c(22L, 42L, 30L, 40L, 14L, 
30L, 20L, 31L, 14L, 20L, 30L, 24L, 91L, 36L, 13L, 37L, 40L, 27L, 
52L, 15L, 44L, 36L, 30L, 33L, 26L, 12L, 66L, 44L, 39L, 11L, 33L, 
18L, 36L, 11L, 70L, 40L, 18L, 38L, 27L, 11L, 22L, 33L, 40L, 39L, 
24L, 10L, 18L, 22L, 52L, 48L, 30L, 20L, 36L, 27L, 24L, 18L, 30L, 
52L, 35L, 16L, 20L, 22L, 48L, 33L, 36L, 28L, 45L, 56L, 18L, 30L, 
22L, 45L, 8L, 45L, 28L, 27L, 44L, 45L, 27L, 24L, 29L, 36L, 32L, 
40L, 9L, 44L, 34L, 27L, 14L, 40L, 60L, 12L, 44L, 30L, 16L, 60L, 
44L, 39L, 35L, 28L, 55L, 32L, 44L, 34L, 48L, 22L, 11L, 30L, 24L, 
12L, 27L, 39L, 63L, 7L, 56L, 24L, 48L, 12L, 20L, 40L, 21L, 91L, 
40L, 24L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 27L, 10L, 40L, 48L, 32L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 
36L, 35L, 33L, 10L, 21L, 18L, 30L, 36L, 43L, 27L, 36L, 35L, 13L, 
9L, 33L, 10L, 20L, 27L, 39L, 65L, 50L, 36L, 16L, 33L, 40L, 40L, 
45L, 21L, 65L, 16L, 44L, 72L, 13L, 60L, 18L, 33L, 9L, 39L, 40L, 
30L, 40L, 22L, 18L, 7L, -16L, 14L, 63L, 40L, 44L, 32L, 48L, 24L, 
33L, 36L, 14L, 22L, 44L, 12L, 56L, 36L, 35L, 27L, 30L, 36L, 20L, 
29L, 35L, 50L, 34L, 26L, 44L, 26L, 40L, 22L, 14L, 18L, 32L, 40L, 
30L, 40L, 70L, 30L, 56L, 42L, 32L, 7L, 33L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 36L, 
46L, 20L, 38L, 36L, 42L, 11L, 55L, 9L, 8L, 55L, 27L, 50L, 31L, 
34L, 52L, 27L, 78L, 50L, 32L, 36L, 60L, 22L, 30L, 48L, 36L, 42L, 
16L, 35L, 31L, 22L, 33L, 39L, 16L, 11L, 41L, 34L, 24L, 36L, 20L, 
18L, 32L, 27L, 8L, 20L, 38L, 16L, 36L, 31L, 32L, 27L, 24L, 16L, 
30L, 40L, 50L, 33L, 27L, 45L, 35L, 21L, 36L, 22L, 7L, 36L, 40L, 
22L, 9L, 29L, 6L, 20L, 22L, 38L, 24L, 66L, 43L, 31L, 39L, 44L, 
30L, 60L, 44L, 40L, 36L, 45L, 33L, 39L, 8L, 60L, 60L, 35L, 24L, 
40L, 4L, 60L, 39L, 32L, 56L, 29L, 7L, 36L, 28L, 36L, 40L, 50L, 
36L, 20L, 38L, 36L, 29L, 43L, 20L, 14L, 31L, 27L, 38L, 56L, 39L, 
29L, 16L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 29L, 10L, 24L, 38L, 55L, 30L, 30L, 40L, 
28L, 40L, 16L, 10L, 32L, 16L, 48L, 26L, 15L, 16L, 8L, 44L, 11L, 
20L, 48L, 20L, 35L, 10L, 29L, 28L, 7L, 36L, 24L, 29L, 55L, 63L, 
24L, 36L, 33L, 26L, 34L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 39L, 22L, 32L, 33L, 
38L, 78L, 20L, 22L, 27L, 18L, 24L, 24L, 44L, 20L, 30L, 28L, 52L, 
36L, 45L, 78L, 20L, 36L, 18L, 12L, 15L, 28L, 40L, 30L, 33L, 20L, 
18L, 37L, 41L, 39L, 40L, 14L, 13L, 9L, 50L, 31L, 11L, 12L, 31L, 
39L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 40L, 30L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 30L, 33L, 24L, 22L, 
20L, 7L, 41L, 40L, 36L, 18L, 20L, 5L, 10L, 24L, 24L, 72L, 18L, 
33L, 22L, 20L, 18L, 36L, 18L, 36L, 31L, 18L, 24L, 27L, 52L, 10L, 
32L, 31L, 20L, 18L, 36L, 30L, 24L, 24L, 40L, 27L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 
21L, 36L, 40L, 60L, 42L, 36L, 39L, 10L, 20L, 33L, 35L, 26L, 35L, 
18L, 32L, 36L, 33L, 60L, 12L, 33L, 8L, 20L, 13L, 33L, 39L, 26L, 
21L, 37L, 44L, 18L, 60L, 55L, 36L, 11L, 32L, 27L, 36L, 44L, 22L, 
33L, 21L, 14L, 30L, 20L, 27L, 39L, 33L, 18L, 12L, 40L, 8L, 31L, 
36L, 34L, 66L, 45L, 22L, 36L, 38L, 8L, 20L, 28L, 36L, 10L, 45L, 
44L, 44L, 22L, 31L, 45L, 20L, 12L, 96L, 9L, 27L, 40L, 10L, 35L, 
11L, 30L, 36L, 37L, 34L, 7L, 18L, 34L, 33L, 12L, 30L, 14L, 52L, 
51L, 20L, 36L, 41L, 20L, 30L, 8L, 36L, 40L, 41L, 21L, 29L, 20L, 
40L, 16L, 44L, 22L, 33L, 36L, 33L, 32L, 21L, 18L), size = c(59.7, 
57.82, 61.88, 52.64, 74.53, 59.71, 53.76, 68.51, 56.32, 69.47, 
66.09, 80.84, 62.05, 70.47, 53.5, 55.58, 68.46, 129.14, 58, 63.55, 
81.77, 71.22, 59.86, 60.16, 62.32, 53.02, 72.8, 58.91, 98.16, 
51.29, 96.54, 55.03, 53.72, 53.93, 72.36, 148.61, 94.18, 57.18, 
82.31, 74.44, 62.23, 50.9, 56.42, 62.22, 55.55, 63.98, 60.17, 
51.01, 55.28, 51.55, 57.29, 68.84, 52.08, 64.43, 56.65, 55.21, 
64.51, 82.75, 61.64, 72.43, 61.12, 66.16, 53.34, 92.03, 56.27, 
90.31, 67.94, 74.69, 56.37, 82.99, 63, 55.23, 52.43, 63.52, 59.57, 
68.18, 71.1, 93.35, 66.81, 79.09, 58.44, 65.97, 60.51, 68.63, 
62.18, 67.54, 70.87, 55.8, 72.01, 62.1, 56.8, 73.26, 55.18, 79.23, 
80.47, 85.2, 62.79, 116.55, 60.66, 73.58, 66.86, 50.87, 78.69, 
69.6, 67.51, 55.98, 51.06, 65.06, 62.15, 75.94, 127.04, 61.73, 
55.3, 67.37, 72.8, 72.99, 76.73, 105.89, 58.98, 50.2, 56.87, 
54.4, 75.06, 57.05, 100.13, 53.62, 96.71, 76.5, 50.05, 98.89, 
69.65, 64.97, 76, 76.9, 53.9, 51.26, 120.42, 59.44, 74.71, 88.47, 
70.04, 60.31, 65.11, 59.2, 91.29, 156.28, 50.74, 50.36, 67.11, 
63.82, 95.28, 94.44, 117.79, 63.16, 69.23, 59.55, 58.21, 56.18, 
88.16, 50.7, 100.39, 55.31, 96.4, 84.74, 58.17, 72.63, 77.33, 
71.51, 55.8, 50.01, 128.76, 97.48, 100.15, 93.42, 66.51, 68.59, 
68.99, 64.44, 56.23, 63.2, 72.3, 65.66, 105.07, 60.28, 86.13, 
110.22, 62.73, 57.94, 62.57, 87.13, 63.6, 58.02, 52.21, 51.97, 
50.79, 76.22, 61.8, 57.36, 65.28, 54.2, 51.97, 68.69, 88.17, 
163.95, 54.84, 57.54, 59.83, 93.2, 96.63, 83.65, 64.08, 67.54, 
56.5, 66.35, 51.07, 52.89, 70.55, 56.65, 53.4, 86.33, 70.61, 
67.36, 53.14, 51.3, 83.09, 70.05, 91.6, 73.22, 57.68, 55.73, 
50.86, 56.54, 58.3, 50.54, 57.1, 61.99, 68.56, 51.74, 84.97, 
64.23, 89.49, 70.05, 67.17, 50.42, 70, 54.42, 50.92, 65.16, 61.19, 
59.19, 52.54, 77.22, 57, 79.96, 50.97, 60.89, 71.32, 55.56, 61.16, 
56.87, 98.59, 61.56, 54.82, 57.47, 57.11, 115.72, 64.93, 74.47, 
50.51, 52.34, 66.39, 65.93, 102.5, 50.33, 56.73, 56.91, 60.99, 
57.78, 57.7, 51.5, 69.85, 69.15, 60.25, 82.08, 70.97, 83.68, 
53.6, 75.01, 57.12, 54.5, 66.56, 75.13, 54.22, 51.89, 74.67, 
52.73, 75.23, 72.47, 85.55, 95.83, 69.57, 64.06, 50.57, 56.75, 
61.55, 71.86, 80.5, 54.23, 63.31, 68.46, 55.7, 57.36, 53.92, 
56.37, 61.8, 70.6, 70.66, 50.67, 60.54, 63.76, 50.15, 52.05, 
57.79, 137.02, 60.04, 54.54, 61.26, 54.61, 74.23, 58.92, 133.96, 
81.92, 52.82, 62.43, 68.68, 64.25, 68.03, 51.02, 66.03, 59.14, 
76.63, 55.08, 63.23, 65.16, 119.96, 58.35, 55.06, 56.06, 101.88, 
75.57, 50.04, 54.3, 62.45, 87.08, 55.06, 89.23, 84.48, 59.18, 
56.43, 55.69, 82.28, 52.83, 75.31, 89.25, 81.79, 53.87, 105.56, 
78.46, 85, 67.81, 59.24, 66.66, 72.39, 101.08, 62.56, 50.54, 
69.41, 51.65, 64.07, 59.54, 107.77, 68.11, 52.08, 68.64, 57.47, 
73.06, 50.46, 80.55, 53.98, 83.86, 51.57, 54.06, 53.4, 57.77, 
78.37, 73.71, 69.94, 61.84, 95.06, 62.9, 52.99, 54.63, 60.56, 
56.58, 91.19, 68.18, 52.46, 70.93, 60.58, 66.81, 114.96, 50.64, 
65.38, 105.16, 53.48, 56.79, 65.06, 59.78, 58.05, 82.69, 96.74, 
54.33, 51.82, 53.61, 100.85, 82.82, 56.22, 63.22, 61.07, 63.56, 
64.21, 60.65, 74.41, 83.65, 58.86, 55.28, 58.89, 50.77, 61.39, 
99.76, 64.47, 55.57, 59.9, 50.52, 67, 51.54, 58.31, 61.66, 52.09, 
139.93, 50.7, 72.92, 62.09, 65.7, 69.98, 63.88, 55.49, 70.64, 
103.73, 103.08, 63.13, 75.35, 50.08, 91.13, 81.84, 63.92, 138.23, 
74.83, 55.53, 50.64, 79.08, 70.31, 55.47, 57.69, 51.92, 62.38, 
106.57, 50.33, 73.86, 69.18, 74.17, 51.19, 82.32, 54.32, 50.5, 
60.16, 78.09, 54.39, 55.65, 77, 51.04, 52.55, 52.1, 102.15, 73.92, 
58.48, 60.03, 53.82, 55.99, 83.88, 54.18, 53.39, 91.78, 77.82, 
51.09, 55.82, 57.75, 69.62, 90.51, 55.92, 101.93, 69.92, 79.5, 
54.49, 98.18, 62.8, 72.09, 89.24, 70.22, 57.42, 60.62, 53.66, 
88.91, 98.53, 64.82, 65.22, 73.17, 54.2, 62.56, 52.91, 54.07, 
58.96, 89.26, 99.91, 58.53, 57.03, 66.47, 53.95, 72.3, 50.6, 
65.28, 70.05, 58.37, 63.02, 67.92, 69.37, 53.35, 95.61, 62.83, 
68.02, 64.34, 57.39, 61.37, 57.46, 64.17, 73.06, 63.26, 83.23, 
51.66, 55.24, 103.24, 67.28, 103.45, 84.28, 51, 75.49, 68.42, 
51.94, 101.5, 64.34, 67.41, 60.68, 88.64, 71.32, 86.52, 78.73, 
53.76, 95.93, 57.2, 64.24, 65.1, 69.97, 73.97, 57.72, 65.4, 51.24, 
51.71, 73.07, 67.71, 53.03, 87.81, 80.53, 60.49, 63.01, 70.84, 
95.22, 62.86, 55.34, 76.21, 65.86)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 
109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 
132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 
143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 
154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 
165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 
176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 
187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 
198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 
209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 
220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 
231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 
242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 
253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 
264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 
275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 
286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 
297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 
308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 
319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 
330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 
341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 
352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 
363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 
374L, 375L, 376L, 377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 
385L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 
396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 
407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 
418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 
429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 
440L, 441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 
451L, 452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 
462L, 463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 
473L, 474L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 
484L, 485L, 486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 
495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 
506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 
517L, 518L, 519L, 520L, 521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 
528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 
539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 543L, 544L, 545L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 
550L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 
561L, 562L, 563L, 564L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 
572L, 573L, 574L, 575L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 
583L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 
594L, 595L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 599L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: One of the amounts is negative because consumption for observation 180 is -16, which results in a negative bill.  If you do `boxplot(amounts ~ data$housemembers)` you should get the display you were looking for.

Comment: If you think some of the numbers that the function calculates are wrong, it would be helpful if you could identify a couple of examples and tell us what the number is you expect to find.